# escaping string - php in html element

Tags: php, html

i know this is really obvious but i just don't know what I'm missing.

```
$option[] = "<option value='user' selected=' " . ($row[5]=='admin') ? echo 'selected' : null. "'>user </option>";`
```

thanks

Comment: What's the problem? `'` don't have to be escaped in a double quote string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$option[] = '<option value="user" . ($row[5]=='admin' ? 'selected' : '') . '>user </option>';`
```

Three differences from your code:

1. I reversed your use of quotes...easier to wrap a PHP string that contains HTML in single quotes (since HTML uses double quotes).
2. I modified the parenthesis around your ternary operator...it was only wrapped around the condition, and not the true/false return values.
3. In your "true" return value in the ternary operation, you were calling `echo`, which isn't necessary in a concatenation operation.

Comment: awesome it worked, however why does yours work not mine?? please explain

Comment: @dgamma3: Because you cannot use `echo` there.

Comment: HTML uses "Whatever quotes you like", they *can* be double quotes, but single quotes are fine. (You can use no quotes at all if the attribute value consists entirely of letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58). )

Comment: Good comment...this is true about HTML and XHTML.

Comment: @AJ actually i found another error. when i use your code i get this in firefox. 

<option ""="" value="user">user</option>
<option "="" "selected="selected" value="user">admin</option>

where are the "="" coming from???

Comment: Hrrm...that's definitely odd.  I made a small change...it's not necessary in HTML to say `selected="selected"`.  You can just say `<option value="something" selected>something</option>`.  I changed my answer to do it that way...not sure if it will help but give it a try.

Comment: ok now im getting this: <option "selected"="" value="user">user </option>
however i think you broke your code above, i used: $option[] = '<option value="user" "' . ($row[5]=='user' ? 'selected' : '') . '">user </option>', anyway ill check your response in the morning. thanks and good night

Comment: No that looks right...unless you are expecting SELECTED to be set.  I'm not sure what the value of `$row[5]` is.  Some browsers choose to render the `selected="selected"` as XHTML compliant, even if you only use the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to write

```
value=\'user\'
```

Just do

```
value='user'
```

Escaping is needed when you use the same quote marks like:

```
echo 'Mark\'s dinner';
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'd break it up.  Also, swap your double quotes for single quotes:

```
$option[] = implode('', array(
    '<option value="user" selected="',
    $row[5] == 'admin' ? 'selected' : '',
    '">user</option>'
));
```